# TensorFlow : Transform Tensor based on conditions of features

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conditional-statements

Thank you very much for reading my question. I'm quite new to TensorFlow so sorry if my problem doesn't completely make sense, I have this regression problem :

```
A = Input(shape=(8))
A0 = A[:,0:4]
A1 = A[:,4:8]
A0 = layers.Dense(12)(A0)
A1 = layers.Dense(12)(A1)
Z = layers.Concatenate()([A0,A1])
Z = layers.Dense(1)(Z)
model = Model(inputs=A, outputs=Z)
```

wherein the input there are two sets of features, `observation A0 && A1`  `ie.[temperature, humidity, UV, pollutants]` from `two separate devices`.

1. if I knew there is an interdependency between these two sets and I want to `transform` `A0` based on the output of `Dense()(A1)` something like  ----> `A0 depends on the features found within [A1 ?!@?#-> A0]`
2. and I also want final layer `Z to only depends on A0`

what kind of method should I use? would something like this make sense? or Tf.Cond or if conditions?

```
A0 = layers.Dense(12)(A0)
A1 = layers.Dense(12)(A1)
Z = layers.Concatenate()([A0,A1])
Z = layers.Dense(12)(Z)
Z = A0 + Z
Z = layers.Dense(1)(Z)
```

I'm looking for something that seems better looking and elegant, or may you please point out a path like some relevant studies that I can look at?

I think my main problem is I don't even know what to look at, as it is not exactly an `if condition`/`tf.case` problem

Thank you very much for your time

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you mean with an actual code example?